# C++: How to read input from a text file in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I running from console I do the following:

```
./a.out < Input.txt
```

How can I do the same in CodeBlocks while debugging?

Comment: Try the support forums at http://forums.codeblocks.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can (but see my comment above). The only way of setting the command line for an app in CB is on a per-project basis and does not seem to easily allow redirection. This seems to me to be a major deficiency in most of the widely used IDE's -  I'd like to see a dialog pop up on run which allowed you to specify a command line and which remembered your last used command lines.

Answer (score 7):

This thread in the CodeBlocks forums has the answer http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=8522.0. Project Menu -> Set program's arguments. The alternative is editing the project file. If your file Input.txt is really a few input arguments that should work.

If you are using it for inputing data, just for debugging you could pass the name of the file as an argument, open the file inside your program and read from it, instead of using input redirection.